# Use email created on cpanel in django

Tags: python, django, cpanel, namecheap

I have created an email id on my cpanel, I want to use it in django.

As for gmail we write,

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

What should we write for the id that has been created using cpanel.

I have no idea regarding this as I am a begineer.

Comment: You may have to do a web search for `cpanel smtp settings for your hosting provider` as cpanel is just a admin tool, but the actual settings to use varies from host to host.  Once you have that information, you should be able to add it to what you have above and test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me I have a cpanel email created on [NameCheap](https://namecheap.com), during development I successfully configured the email. I was able to send the email from the configured one. But the Email was not using SSL or TLS because setting up the secure one was raising an error.

```
#MY EMAIL SETTING
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.your_main_domain'  #Hosted on namecheap Ex: mail.pure.com
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 26 #This will be different based on your Host, for Namecheap I use this`
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your full email address' # Ex: info@pure.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password' # for the email you created through cPanel. The password for that
```

If you are using Django All auth remember to set to use same email to send password reset links

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Thanks

Comment: bro can i ask you i try your method but it say error 
App 634174 output: smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (501, b'<=?utf-8?q?Creative?=>: sender address must contain a domain', '=?utf-8?q?Creative?=')

Answer (score 1):

I have cpanel email created with hostafrica with SSL and TLS enable, also hosted my application on aws but decided not to use AWS SES. so I configure my email backends as follow:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.my_domain'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587 # I use this for SSL
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "no-reply@my_domain"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "email_Password"
```