# Incorrect Authentication Data

Tags: python, django, django-mailer

I tryng to send email in my django projects.

Here is my settings:-

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'gmail.com'
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply.marketage@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
```

I am getting this error

```
(535, b'Incorrect authentication data')
```

I turned on less secure app also.

I also tried my cpanel Email. For that my setting was

```
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.marketage.io'
# EMAIL_PORT = 587
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# # EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
# EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'noreply@marketage.io'
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

For this settings I get the same error. I dont know what causing this issue. But My email was working 4 days ago and it worked just fine. But Suddenly Its not working. I tried to debug my code for that I used Gmail SMTP in my localhost. In Localhost its working completely fine but its not working when I try to send email from live server.

Is there any solution??

Thanks In Advance

Comment: try to read this https://www.nativespace.com/mynative/knowledgebase/61/Error-535---Incorrect-authentication-data.html and i advice you to use this `EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"` where is your web site hosted ?

Comment: I hosted my website in Cpanel @amadousow

Comment: alright i do not know it,but try out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547115/15042684

Comment: Not working @amadousow